# *Edited for more explanation...*I need the values of one column in SQL, but those values separated by how many different values there are

Tags: sql-server

I have a query I am trying to build for results for a survey. The questions store integers, ranging 1-5 depending on what the end user selects. These are stored in separate columns in my Response table (for example, StaffRelationships, StaffQuality, StaffInfo) and each one will store a 1-5 value depending on  how the end user rates them.

What I am trying to do, is create a query to list how many of EACH integer response for each question.

So for StaffRelationships, I want to display how many scored a 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 and display this out.

I currently have:

```
select distinct StaffRelationships

From FamilySatisfactionResponses
```

Which returns:

```
   StaffRelationships
1        1
2        2
```

I have 3 entries for this question in my database, with values 1,2, and 1. So I need it show show there were 2 people who rated 1, and 1 person who rated 2.

I am a bit lost on how to make this happen though. Any suggestions?

**edit since I apparently do not have enough information....**

StaffRelationships is one column in a table called FamilySatisfactionResponses.  I have a number of columns in that table (again... for example.. StaffRelationships, StaffQuality, StaffInfo)
These columns hold an integer. This will eventually be pulled from VB. There is a web form where they use a slider to select a number 1-5 to rate their satisfaction on what is being asked. That number is stored as an integer in the corresponding question column. In this case, I have the integers 1,2, and 1 saved in StaffRelationships in 3 different rows. Selecting top 1000 rows of my FamilySatsfactionResponses shows up like so:

```
first name   last name   email.........StaffRelationships
Sally        Jones       example@email.com  1
bob          vance       another@email.com  2
jane         doe         email@email.com    1
```

So, I have stored integers in StaffRelationships. I am trying to create a stored procedure to output how many of EACH POSSIBLE RESULT 1-5 are in this column. So, when we create a webform to show the appropriate department the results of the survey, they can see how many people rated this question a 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5. 
As pointed out above, I tried using distinct and it pulls what is showed. I know that is not all I need, but am looking for direction on where to go from what I am trying.

Hopefully, this is explained enough......

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Unfortunately there aren't enough details here to offer any help. Please see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for how to ask a question.

Comment: There are enough details. @catxlearningxcode, I'd recommend looking into `group by` instead of `distinct`. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: I apologize, what more could I possibly add? I listed what I am currently doing, what it returns and what I am trying to accomplish, and tagged it under SQL server which is what I am using. I don't think there is anything more I can add to this unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you Matt, I will try looking at group by!

Comment: Please share the source data and what you expect the output to be.

Comment: `select distinct StaffRelationships` will return a single column. Not two columns as shown in the question

Comment: See edited question for even more explanation than what I had. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where you need to think **very clearly** about what you want. When you break down your comments above, you appear to want an output that looks something like this:

```
QuestionName        1    2    3    4    5
-------------      ---  ---  ---  ---  ---
StaffRelationships  2    1    0    0    0
```

Assuming that this is correct, this query will provide that output. NOTE: this is only one possible way to do it. There are others available, some of which may be better than this.

```
SELECT 
    'StaffRelationships' AS QuestionName,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN StaffRelationships = 1
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS [1],
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN StaffRelationships = 2
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS [2],
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN StaffRelationships = 3
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS [3],
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN StaffRelationships = 4
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS [4],
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN StaffRelationships = 5
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS [5]
FROM FamilySatisfactionResponses
WHERE ISNULL(StaffRelationships, 0) <> 0
```

A better option might use the PIVOT operator, but this is a quick solution to your problem

Comment: YES this is what I was looking for. Thank you. I am obviously new here.